# android-Picasso callback prevents garbage collecting

Tags: android, android-fragments, garbage-collection, picasso

I use Picasso library in my android app to load images. I need to get notified when the image is loaded successfully, so I use:

```
Picasso.get().load(imageURL).into(imageView, new Callback() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess() {
            // do sth
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(Exception e) {

        }
    });
```

as it is mentioned in Picasso library documentation, `The Callback param is a strong reference and will prevent your Activity or Fragment from being garbage collected.` due to this reason, the memory used by my app grows so much after replacing a number of fragments-which all use the callback.

how to get rid of the callback and allow the fragments to be garbage collected after `onSuccess` method has been run?

Answer (score 1):

Add a tag when using Picasso:

```
        Picasso.get().load("imageURL").tag("custom_tag").into(imageView, new Callback() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess() {
            // do sth
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(Exception e) {

        }
    });
```

And then before replacing/removing your fragment or quitting your activity, cancel the task by calling:

```
Picasso.get().cancelTag("custom_tag");
```

Note that the `callback` will automatically be removed after `onSuccess()` is called. So the offered solution is useful when the callback has not yet fulfilled.